# What does it mean for a 1-cocycle to split?

Tags: number-theory, homology-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $K$ be a finite Galois extension of a field $k$. Let $X$ be a variety defined over $k.$ In a paper I am reading, it mentions splitting of 1 -cocycles. For example, "a 1-cocycle $c \in Z^1(\Gamma(K/k),X)$ splits." What does this mean?

Comment: Which paper? A link will help you get better answers

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in Lang's paper "On Quasi-Algebraic Closure." I think it just means that it is a coboundary.